# Making a pdf machine readable with illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, automation

I work as UX designer, as such I have a CV which I've designed in Adobe Illustrator.

I think its a very nice CV design. It has a good data flow, its readable, its well sectioned, etc...  for human readers it works well.

However; when it comes to uploading it into certain systems it always becomes totally warped. Machines just don't know what to do with it. They completely mix up locations and jobs and dates and it looks like I'm some guy with 1 year of experience working at a company called Sweden.

No big deal when I am manually uploading myself however I know many recruiters make heavy use of machines to do a first trawl of CVs before human eyes ever see them.... I need to fix this.

So the question is, in adobe illustrator, is there anyway to design the machine reading flow so that you can make it match the human reading flow?

Is there a technical setting somewhere for setting this up or must you do some tricks with your actual design?

Comment: Form vs. function... it may look nice, but you may need to rethink or "dummy" it down to be usable. The *primary* goal should be usability and appearance is very much secondary.

Comment: Except it does function well. For humans. I have no idea how to make it function well for machines. Thats what I'm asking

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a complete bug-free solution, but i think it could be a major improvement to create a Tagged PDF. Also, not sure about the latest AI CC version, but InDesign may be better optimized for exporting Tagged PDF, so you may need to re-build your CV via InDesign. Research this:

- https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-pdf-files.html
- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1732445
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397984/what-is-tagged-pdf
- https://indesignsecrets.com/reasons-create-tagged-pdf.php